# Title of the chapter breaking page layout

Tags: header-footer, thesis, books, layout

this is probably a dumb issue but I don't know how to solve it in a clean and efficient way.
I am writing my thesis with the standard book layout. The problem is that the title of one of the chapter is pretty long and thus the header breaks the page layout:
[image]

This is a MWE.

> ```
>   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside, openright]{book}
>
>     \begin{document}
>     \chapter{The Knower Paradox in light of Justification Logic}
>     
>     blablaa
>     \newpage
>     
>     blabla
>     
>     \end{document}
> ```

Comment: Have you tried `\chapter[Short Title]{Long Title}`?  The short title then gets typeset into the table of contents and (I think) the header, while the long title still shows up where you would expect it to.  Or do you need the long title to still be in the table of contents?

Comment: The `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report`) enables 3 different title texts --- one for the ToC another for the headers and the main one.

Comment: The `[toctitles]` option of titlesec uses the `shorttitle` for headers and the `longtitle` for the table of contents, if needed.